# Как расширить Bluetooth Low Energy датчик на несколько устройств?

Tags: android, bluetooth, железо

Есть BLE датчик пульса Sigma R1 Blue, смарфон Sony Xperia Z2 (android 4.4) и велокомп Topeak PanoComputer с поддержкой BLE датчиков.

Одновременно BLE датчик может быть подключен только к одному устройству (например или только к смарту или только к велокомпу). Конечно же производитель велокомпа предусмотрел эту проблему и написал кривоватый софт чтобы можно выводить данные на велокомп при подключении датчика к смарту. К сожалению, как это обычно бывает, юзабельность получилась на нуле - запустить еще одну софтину можно, но вот данные на велокомпе выводятся в сильно обрезном виде, а это очень критично (есть только текущие значения).

Вопрос: есть ли способ как-то расшарить (программно/аппаратно/др) BLE датчик сразу на два устройства? (т.е. чтобы датчик был виден и на сматре и на велокомпе).

Comment: все зависит от датчика и "велокомпа". Непонятно, причем тут вообще Android?

Comment: BLE это же звезда => сам по датчик может подключиться только к одному устройству (т.е. датчик то как раз абсолютно правильно работает), из-за чего и возникают все проблемы :( Android тут при том, что умеет работать с BLE и вполне возможно что можно как-то программно расшарить датчик еще и на велокомп.

Comment: может. Вот только одному Билу Гейтсу известно, в каком формате данные ждет велокомп. Поэтому и зависит все от него.

Comment: Велокомп ждет сигнал обычного стандартного HRM датчика (профиль у него известен), поэтому если можно как-то заставить смарт притвориться вторым датчиком, который будет просто передавать данные от настоящего датчика, то проблема бы решилась.

Answer (score 0):

Как писали выше: простой вариант заставить смартфон выступать в роли датчика. Копать в сторону Android GATT Server. Профиль датчика известен. Собственно, можно тупо повторять (ретранслировать) все данные полученные смартом от датчика.